# How do I change a drupal form name attribute to something else?

Tags: forms, drupal, attributes, drupal-6, name-attribute

I'm using a Drupal 6 custom form, and I want to change the form name attribute to something else. Is this possible?

For example, I have this.

```
<input type="text" name="field" maxlength="128" id="edit-name" value="">
```

I want to change it to the following.

```
<input type="text" data-name="field" maxlength="128" id="edit-name" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the new attribute by using [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/6.x) and adding a `#data-name` to the array for the field you are trying to update.  I don't think you can easily remove the name attribute in Drupal 6, but I've never tried. [More on the Drupal 6 Form API](https://www.drupal.org/node/751826).

*Take Note: Drupal 6 is no longer officially supported by the community. While there are some places that are offering long term support for Drupal 6, you should plan to move to Drupal 7 or 8 soon.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I need to remove the name attribute.

Comment: You can try to set the #name to an empty string or false and see if it gets removed (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/6.x#name). If that doesn't work I think to remove that attribute altogether you'll need to override the theme function for the form fields.